# Laravel: Do not import duplicate datas Excel

Tags: php, laravel

I have an issue when importing datas from an Excel file. My import controller is working just fine but it adds duplicate datas and i need to import the same datas often.

This is my attempt which doesn't work.

My postImportAttendee controller (My project is using Attendize):

```
  public function postImportAttendee(Request $request, $event_id)
    {
        $rules = [
            'ticket_id'  => 'required|exists:tickets,id,account_id,' . \Auth::user()->account_id,
            'attendees_list' => 'required|mimes:csv,txt,xlsx|max:5000|',
        ];

        $messages = [
            'ticket_id.exists' => trans("Controllers.ticket_not_exists_error"),
        ];

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json([
                'status'   => 'error',
                'messages' => $validator->messages()->toArray(),
            ]);

        }
        $enveloppe = [];
        $ticket_id = $request->get('ticket_id');
        $event = Event::findOrFail($event_id);
        $ticket_price = 0;
        $email_attendee = $request->get('email_ticket');
        $num_added = 0;
        if ($request->file('attendees_list')) {

          $the_file = Excel::load($request->file('attendees_list')->getRealPath(), function ($reader) {
            })->get();

            if(!empty($the_file) && $the_file->count()){
            // Loop through
            foreach ($the_file as $key => $value) {


                    if (array_key_exists($value->enveloppe, $enveloppe))
                        continue;

                    $rows[] = ['enveloppe' => $value->enveloppe, 'first_name' => $value->first_name, 'last_name' => $value->last_name, 'company' => $value->company, 'email' => $value->email, 'sender' => $value->sender];


                    $enveloppe[$value->enveloppe] = true; // or array_push

                  }

                  if (!empty($rows['enveloppe']) && !empty($rows['last_name'])) {

                    $num_added++;
                    $attendee_first_name = strip_tags($rows['first_name']);
                    $attendee_last_name = strip_tags($rows['last_name']);
                    $attendee_email = $rows['email'];
                    $attendee_enveloppe = $rows['enveloppe'];
                    $attendee_company = strip_tags($rows['company']);
                    $attendee_sender = strip_tags($rows['sender']);

                    error_log($ticket_id . ' ' . $ticket_price . ' ' . $email_attendee);


                    /**
                     * Create the order
                     */
                    $order = new Order();
                    $order->first_name = $attendee_first_name;
                    $order->last_name = $attendee_last_name;
                    $order->enveloppe = $attendee_enveloppe;
                    $order->company = $attendee_company;
                    $order->sender = $attendee_sender;
                    $order->email = $attendee_email;
                    $order->order_status_id = config('attendize.order_complete');
                    $order->amount = $ticket_price;
                    $order->account_id = Auth::user()->account_id;
                    $order->event_id = $event_id;

                    // Calculating grand total including tax
                    $orderService = new OrderService($ticket_price, 0, $event);
                    $orderService->calculateFinalCosts();
                    $order->taxamt = $orderService->getTaxAmount();

                    if ($orderService->getGrandTotal() == 0) {
                        $order->is_payment_received = 1;
                    }

                    $order->save();

                    /**
                     * Update qty sold
                     */
                    $ticket = Ticket::scope()->find($ticket_id);
                    $ticket->increment('quantity_sold');
                    $ticket->increment('sales_volume', $ticket_price);
                    $ticket->event->increment('sales_volume', $ticket_price);

                    /**
                     * Insert order item
                     */
                    $orderItem = new OrderItem();
                    $orderItem->title = $ticket->title;
                    $orderItem->quantity = 1;
                    $orderItem->order_id = $order->id;
                    $orderItem->unit_price = $ticket_price;
                    $orderItem->save();

                    /**
                     * Update the event stats
                     */
                    $event_stats = new EventStats();
                    $event_stats->updateTicketsSoldCount($event_id, 1);
                    // $event_stats->updateTicketRevenue($ticket_id, $ticket_price);

                    /**
                     * Create the attendee
                     */
                    $attendee = new Attendee();
                    $attendee->first_name = $attendee_first_name;
                    $attendee->last_name = $attendee_last_name;
                    $attendee->email = $attendee_email;
                    $attendee->enveloppe = $attendee_enveloppe;
                    $attendee->company = $attendee_company;
                    $attendee->sender = $attendee_sender;
                    $attendee->event_id = $event_id;
                    $attendee->order_id = $order->id;
                    $attendee->ticket_id = $ticket_id;
                    $attendee->account_id = Auth::user()->account_id;
                    $attendee->reference_index = 1;
                    $attendee->save();

                    if ($email_attendee == '1') {
                        $this->dispatch(new SendAttendeeInvite($attendee));
                    }
                }
            };
        }

        session()->flash('message', $num_added . ' Attendees Successfully Invited');

        return response()->json([
            'status'      => 'success',
            'id'          => $attendee->id,
            'redirectUrl' => route('showEventAttendees', [
                'event_id' => $event_id,
            ]),
        ]);
    }
```

I want the duplicates datas to be skipped and new ones to be added.

What i'm missing?

Thank you!

Comment: You can use Collection. Make a collection from excel data and use [unique](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-unique)

Answer (score 0):

Before insert data into table you should check any unique data that already exists.example email id, if the email already exists skip insert.

Comment: can you expand on your answer with some code to help the OP get started with what to do/how to solve the problem?